# MIPS String Slicing | Detect a given word in a string

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, slice, mips

I am trying to make a function that detects if a part of a string is equal to a given word.

I thought of going through the string with a nested loop and detecting if the substring found would be equal to the word given. However, I don't know of to slice a string with a nested loop. I am only able to come up with a program that is able to detect if a character of a string is equal to a given character by looping through it.

Here is what I made:

```
    la $a0,string #load address of string
    lb $a1,orig   #load original character
    lb $a2,new    #load new character
    li $a3,0      #load replace with zero first
    li $t0,0      #load index
    loop:
    lb $t0,0($a0) #load character
    beqz $t0,exit #exit when loop finish

    bne $t0,$a1,skip #compare with original character
    sb $a2,0($a0)    #replace character
    add $a3,$a3,1    #increase replace count by one
    skip:
    add $a0,$a0,1    #increase count by one
    j loop
    exit:

    end:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,rprompt
    syscall
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: _"I am only able to come up with a program that is able to detect if a character of a string is equal to a given character"_. Well, you will have to do the comparison character by character. An algorithm for finding a word in a string could look like `const char *w = word;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] && !found; ++i) {
    w = (str[i] == *w) ? w+1 : word;
    found = !*w;
    }`

Comment: Hey @Michael, thank you for your answer. Could you please translate your code to Python or Java so I can understand it better? I am not familiar with C++